# Why does my network work with an incorrect broadcast ip?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

I have a block of public ips. The network is /28 starting at .80

By that rational, the broadcast ip should be set to .95, however the broadcast ip set in /etc/network/interfaces for every server is .255

This is incorrect according to all online research I have done, yet the network functions normally. I can find nothing affected by the broadcast IP being incorrect.

Also, the .95 ip is available for use. I set up a NAT rule to direct it to a server's private ip and was able to establish an SSH tunnel from outside the network.

How is this possible?

From my limited networking expertise I understand in a block of ips 2 are unavailable to be used by normal hosts because there must be a gateway and a broadcast ip. My network has a gateway (obviously), but all connected hosts have the wrong entry for the broadcast. Yet, everything works...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A wrong boardcast IP would not affect reachability of addresses outside the network/broadcast address range. However, IPs inside that range will be treated as locals and they will not be routed at all.

In your specific case, this means that .96 - .255 IPs are not visible from your servers. However, all other IPs outside your local range (.0 - .255) can be reached without problems.

So, you *have* a problem, but you did not notice it.